# table with about 1 million unique keywords utf_unicode performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a table with 1 million unique keywords in all languages stored in `utf_unicode` format. Lately I have been having problems with selects with each select taking up to 1 second. This is really causing a slowdown in the queries.

The structure for the keyword table is (`keyword_id`, `keyword`, `dirty`) -> The `keyword_id` is the primary key, `keyword` has unique index and `dirty` has a simple index. `keyword` has a `varchar` type with 20 chars max. The `dirty` is a boolean.

The problems are being faced when selecting with "keyword" in the where field. How can I speed this table up.

I am using MySQL with PHP.

**SAMPLE QUERY**

```
SELECT k_id 
FROM table 
WHERE keyword = "movies"
```

Comment: Can you show a sample query that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Is it a MyISAM or InnoDb table?

Comment: Please update the question to include: The table structure (as shown by SHOW CREATE TABLE), the explain plan of the query, and the time taken with various numbers of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a memory table instead of myisam in my experience is goes 10 times faster then myisam. You'll just need another table to rebuild from if the server crashes. Also instead of varchar use char 20. This will make the table a fixed format and mysql will be able to find it's result much faster.

Comment: Apparently, I have read somewhere, that memory tables are slow. I was shocked when I read that but can you please confirm that memory tables will be faster if I did do what you suggest. :)

Comment: In my experience they have been 10 times faster like I said. The only reason I don't do it unless I need to is because of the added pain of having a copy of the tables to rebuild them when mysql restarts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique keywords and if you aren't doing any similarity/"like" queries, then you can create a hash index. That would guarantee a single row lookup.

The minor disadvantage this may have is that creating a hash index may take up more space than a regular index(btree based).

Refrences:

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html